# Split list of objects to sublist without linq

Tags: c#, .net, linq

## Hi guys

I want to get code that's split list of objects to sublist i search on "stackoverflow". I was found this code that's do what i actually want. But i want to do the same without linq ( normal way ) using loop and conditions.

#### **Code example:**

```
public List<object> BL = new List<object>();
List<object> List = new List<object>();
void CreateObj(int count)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        BL.Add(string.Format("No. {0}", i));
    }
}

void SplitObj()
{
    List = BL
        .Select((x, i) => new { Index = i, Value = x })
        .GroupBy(x => x.Index / 12)
        .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList())
        .ToList<object>();
}
```

Comment: Note: the code in **SplitObj** function. **CreateObj** it's function to load objects to array memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So do you want to split a List into a List> it sounds like (and judging by the provided code).

The following is the iterative way to do the same thing:

```
    List<List<object>> newList = new List<List<object>>();
    void SplitObj(int objectsPerPart)
    {
        if (BL == null || BL.Count < 1)
            return;

        List<object> current = new List<object>();
        current.Add(BL[0]);
        for (int i = 1; i < BL.Count; i++)
        {
            if (i % objectsPerPart == 0)
            {
                newList.Add(current);
                current = new List<object>();
            }
            current.Add(BL[i]);
        }
    }
```